# Ask a question of Monte Carlo test

Tags: statistics

I am reading a book, it said:

> The expected power of a Monte Carlo test can be quite good even for
> relatively small values of m. In simple situations (testing means, for
> example), m = 99 may be a good choice. This allows the p-value to be
> expressed simply in two decimal places. In more complicated situations
> (inference concerning higher moments or relationships between
> variables), a value of m = 999 may be more appropriate. The p-value
> resulting from a Monte Carlo test is an estimate based on a sample of
> size m, so in general the larger m is, the better the estimate. In
> practical applications, it is not likely that a decision, other than
> to gather additional data, would be made based on more than two
> significant digits in a p-value.

I am confused about "p-value to be expressed simply
in two decimal places". I don't understand.

Comment: It means usually we look at p values to 2s.f. such as $0.99$ or $0.95$, rather than $p=0.92737485923$

Comment: @GarethMa Yeah, that is also my guess. But m can be any number, if we just need p be two decimal places. I didn't see the connection between m=99 and two decimal places.

Comment: You have your observation and $99$ simulations under the null hypothesis so you can find how proportionately far up your observation is among the $100$ values, giving you an integer divided by $100$, i.e. to two decimal places.  If the null hypothesis is correct and you are counting from $1$, your result will be $0.05$ or less $5\%$ of the time (or at the other extreme, more than $0.95$ $5\%$ of the time).